Cannot create field 'id' in element {buffHave: []}
I want to push data id & duration to buffhave but an error occurs "Cannot create field 'id' in element {buffHave: []}"
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");
const schema = new Schema({
  userId: String,
  buffHave: [{
    id: {
      type: [Number],
      default: [-1]
    },
    duration: Date
  }]
});

module.exports = model("user", schema);

await userData.updateOne(
  {
    userId: user.id
  },
  {
    $push: {
      "buffHave.id": buffId,
      "buffHave.duration": buffs[buffId].duration
    }
  }
);```


Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question. Read: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Format your code and make use of block quotes ```like this```.

In your schema definition, you've defined buffHave as an array of objects with properties id and duration. However, you're trying to push buffId and buffs[buffId].duration directly into buffHave, which is not valid because buffHave is an array of objects, not just an array.
To fix this, you need to push an object with both id and duration properties into the buffHave array. Here's how you can do it:


await userData.updateOne(
  {
    userId: user.id
  },
  {
    $push: {
      buffHave: {
        id: buffId,
        duration: buffs[buffId].duration
      }
    }
  }
);



